# How to order the square bracket elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need the sort the non square bracket element in ascending and sqauare bracket element in descending.

input:

```
9[8] 5[18] [17]2
```

output:

```
2[18] 5[17] [8]9
```

My code:

```
import re
n=int(input())
l=list(map(str,input().split()))
print(l)
r = re.compile("\.|[\[-\]]")
for i in range(0,len(l)):
  l[i]=r.split(l[i])
print(l)
```

I splited the elements but i don't know how to sort this proper manner If you are interested to share your thoughts I will be very happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's unclear what your input is. is it a string? a lit of strings?

Comment: Its a string input

Comment: What's the general format? Can there be nested brackets?

Comment: Is the bracket value before the normal value only on the last position?

Comment: No sir the input is string format...I need the sort the non square bracket element in ascending and square bracket element in descending.

Comment: Sorry sir i typed wrongly i changed

Comment: Why are you doing `n=int(input())`? That doesn't seem to have anything to do with the input.

Answer (score 2):

Easy to extract inside numbers, replace them with a non-digit marker to make extraction of the outside numbers easy as well. Sort each as desired, then fill them back in.

```
import re

s = '9[8] 5[18] [17]2'

inside = re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]', s)
s = re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '[i]', s)
outside = re.findall(r'\d+', s)

outside.sort(key=int)
inside.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
outside = iter(outside)
inside = iter(inside)

s = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda _: next(outside), s)
s = re.sub('i', lambda _: next(inside), s)

print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dDoIwDIXv9xS72xYMCRojmvAW3g1iIKtxEQbphpGnx2XgH3rTpP1OT0@7wV1as0k7HEfddC06ikCIpRlle5kWdCsTX2WyK9aMEG2sVuAhQnzWRpV1zZHlkucqEnnBVtSKsOy57avAPAqEST0L2t79tVHRxJ@C2Po8/ApDpo0T8/Gv4co73AAtZEfs4dNZO0A@t@KdO4ynTpBF0nC@LptKlfR0oAbu7uWwfIzpX@1sO73QoY/HrRjHBw)

Comment: Thank you sir I understood now

Comment: @Heisenberg ["sir"](https://www.google.com/search?q=kelly+bundy)?

Comment: @KellyBundy nice little trick there with the `re.sub` + `lambda`, you learn something new everyday.  [Excuse me madam? 3,000 to 4,000](https://marriedwithchildren.fandom.com/wiki/Kelly_Bundy)